# sourcing environment variable in bashrc: directly vs export from file yields different result - why

Tags: systemd, environment-variables, bashrc

I am running systemd via user (i.e. `enable-linger $USER`) and I interact with services via `systemctl --user`

I noticed a strange issue.

## Sourcing Type 1

In order for the above systemd to work for a user, I need to add `export XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)` inside my `~/.bashrc`

This works fine.

## Sourcing Type 2

When I instead source my bashrc as follows, the systemd does not work:

inside `.bashrc`:

```
source /path_to_file/my_file.env
```

inside `my_file.env`:

```
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/$(id -u)
```

Both Sourcing Type 1 and 2 yield the same result when I do `echo $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` so I decided to go with Type 2. However then I noticed that when I do `systemctl --user daemon-reload` the daemon was not running and I got the following error:

```
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

When I revert back to Souring Type 1, the error is gone and all works as expected.

My question is: What is happening that I am missing here? My main confusion stems from the fact that the env variables are the same, but the end results are not.

Comment: `.env` files are not shell scripts and should not be sourced at all. Quoting rules are different, so the value assigned to a name by a `.env` parser may be different than what the shell will assign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the `export` in your .env file, so the variable isn't actually an *environment* variable.

Shell variables are not exported to environment by default. Only assignments to an already exported variable will be re-exported automatically; if `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` is a brand new variable, it will become a shell internal variable unless you use the `export` or `declare -x` builtins. (Or unless the "allexport" shell option is enabled, but using it in .bashrc has some weird gotchas.)

`echo $FOO` "sees" the variable because the expansion of $FOO in command-line is done by the shell interpreter itself, not by the command – 'echo' doesn't have to access the environment at all, whereas 'systemctl' does.

Instead of echo, you could use `declare -p FOO` to have the shell itself tell you the variable's state (including showing the `x` flag if the variable is exported), or use `env` or `printenv` to see what the environment looks like from the point of view of an external process (non-exported shell variables simply won't show up here).

Either way, you should never *need* to do this for interactive logins. This specific variable is supposed to be put in your environment through PAM (by pam_systemd) as soon as you log in – even before your shell is run.

For scripts that need to access another user's services, `systemctl --user -M ${USER}@.host` will make systemctl itself find the specified user's runtime directory and the D-Bus socket.